# Set the font line height of a Xamarin.Forms Label

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms label showing several lines of text and I would like to increase the line height to make the text more readable.

The font properties available on the `Label` and `Span` controls seem limited to font face, size and style.

How can I change the line height?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need a custom control and render that can inherit from the existing ones and handle additional properties. As for iOS (idk about Android) you can use

```
// this goes in the Forms project
public class CustomLabel : Label{
  // make it bindable, shortened for simplicity here
  public double LineHeight {get;set;}
}

// this goes in the iOS project, another one in the Android project
// notice the attribute is before the namespace
[assembly: ExportRendererAttribute (typeof(CustomLabel), typeof(CustomLabelRenderer))]
namespace MyNamespace{
public class CustomLabelRenderer: LabelRenderer
  protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<Frame> e){
    base.OnElementChanged(e);
  // sample only; expand, validate and handle edge cases as needed
    ((UILabel)base.Control).Font.LineHeight = ((CustomLabel)this.Element).LineHeight;
  }

  // if your property is bindable you can handle changes in this method:
  // protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged (object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
}
```

As far as iOS (idk if Android has that feature) you can also use the [UIAppearance](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/introduction_to_the_appearance_api/) of a UILabel to increase line height throughout the app, something in the lines of:

```
UILabel.Appearance.Font.LineHeight = 20f;
```

Comment: I'm trying this, but I'm getting an error for the line `((UILabel)base.Control).Font.LineHeight = ((CustomLabel)this.Element).LineHeight;`, saying "Property or indexer 'UIFont.LineHeight' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only"

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get it to work by defining a custom renderer like the following. First, in your Forms project (PCL), define a custom label and add a LineHeight property:

```
// Put this your forms project
public class CustomLabel : Label
{
    public double LineHeight { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in your iOS project, you define the renderer like this:

```
// Put this in your iOS project
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomLabel), typeof(CustomLabelRenderer))]
namespace MyNamespace
{ 
    public class CustomLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            // Make sure control is not null
            var label = (CustomLabel)Element;
            if (label == null || Control == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var labelString = new NSMutableAttributedString(label.Text);
            var paragraphStyle = new NSMutableParagraphStyle { LineSpacing = (nfloat)label.LineHeight };
            var style = UIStringAttributeKey.ParagraphStyle;
            var range = new NSRange(0, labelString.Length);

            labelString.AddAttribute(style, paragraphStyle, range);
            Control.AttributedText = labelString;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, you would use it on your page like so:

```
new Label {
    Text = "some text",
    LineHeight = 20
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above solutions without succeed. The behaviours are different in Android and iOS, so I worked on a similar solution achieving the same behaviour in both platforms.

```
// Put this your forms project
public class CustomLabel : Label
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty LineHeightProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("LineHeight", typeof(double), typeof(CustomLabel));

    public double LineHeight
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(LineHeightProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LineHeightProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Then, the iOS renderer:

```
// Put this in your iOS project
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomLabel), typeof(CustomLabelRenderer))]
namespace App.iOS.Components
{
    public class CustomLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            var label = (CustomLabel)Element;
            if (label == null || Control == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            double fontSize = label.FontSize;

            //iOS LineSpacing is measured in dp, as the FontSize. So, if we need a LineSpacing of 2, 
            //this LineSpacing must be set to the same value of the FontSize
            nfloat lineSpacing = ((nfloat)label.LineHeight * (nfloat)fontSize) - (nfloat)fontSize;
            if (lineSpacing > 0)
            {
                var labelString = new NSMutableAttributedString(label.Text);
                var paragraphStyle = new NSMutableParagraphStyle { LineSpacing = lineSpacing };
                var style = UIStringAttributeKey.ParagraphStyle;
                var range = new NSRange(0, labelString.Length);

                labelString.AddAttribute(style, paragraphStyle, range);
                Control.AttributedText = labelString;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that, in iOS the LineSpacing property is different from Android:
`LineSpacing = 2` in Android is the equivalent to `LineSpacing = FontSize` in iOS

Finally, the AndroidRenderer:

```
// Put this in your Android project
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomLabel), typeof(CustomLabelRenderer))]
namespace App.Droid.Components
{
    public class CustomLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
    {
        protected CustomLabel CustomLabel { get; private set; }
        public CustomLabelRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement == null)
            {
                this.CustomLabel = (CustomLabel)this.Element;
            }
            double lineSpacing = this.CustomLabel.LineHeight;
            if (lineSpacing > 0)
            {
                this.Control.SetLineSpacing(1f, (float)lineSpacing);
                this.UpdateLayout();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it works